# TabIndex does not work correctly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a windows form application. On the form there are three groupboxs.
Each groupbox contains some controls. Please see the image.
[image: form]

There is a groupbox "flag" that contains a few checkboxs. "flag" is inside in "groupbox1".
I used Tab key to go through each control but it doesn't work for checkboxs in "flag". I did set proper tabindex for each control.

It works for textboxs and buttons but checkboxs.

Why? Thanks for help.

**EDIT**

```
 // groupBox2
        // 
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox10);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox9);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox8);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox7);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.chkStoplight);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.lblStoplight);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.chkIsCount);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.chkExceptionFlag);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.chkIsActive);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.lblIsActive);
        this.groupBox2.Controls.Add(this.lblExceptionFlag);
        this.groupBox3.Controls.Add(this.lblIsCount);
        this.groupBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 201);
        this.groupBox2.Name = "groupBox2";
        this.groupBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(321, 70);
        this.groupBox2.TabIndex = 10;
        this.groupBox2.TabStop = true;
        this.groupBox2.Text = "Flags";

        // 
        // chkStoplight
        // 
        this.chkStoplight.AutoSize = true;
        this.chkStoplight.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(44, 25);
        this.chkStoplight.Name = "chkStoplight";
        this.chkStoplight.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(15, 14);
        this.chkStoplight.TabIndex = 0;
        this.chkStoplight.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;

        In the property, I found TabStop is true for chkStoplight.
```

Comment: please tell us which control gets active after you press tab continuously

Comment: The code is just numbers for tabindex. All controls are active except checkboxs.

Comment: Are you using `System.Windows.Controls.GroupBox` or `System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox`?

Comment: this.groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();

Comment: What are the TabStop/TabIndex settings for groupBox1?

Comment: this.groupBox1.TabIndex = 3;
            this.groupBox1.TabStop = true;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For **System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox**:

You should make sure that your GroupBox `flag` has an appropriate TabIndex set.

From [MSDN - How to: Set the Tab Order on Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-set-the-tab-order-on-windows-forms):

> Additionally, by default, a GroupBox control has its own TabIndex
>   value, which is a whole number. A GroupBox control itself cannot have
>   focus at run time. Thus, each control within a GroupBox has its own
>   decimal TabIndex value, beginning with .0. Naturally, as the TabIndex
>   of a GroupBox control is incremented, the controls within it will be
>   incremented accordingly. If you changed a TabIndex value from 5 to 6,
>   the TabIndex value of the first control in its group automatically
>   changes to 6.0, and so on

Also, make sure the [TabStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.groupbox.tabstop(v=vs.80)) property of your GroupBox `flag` is not set to false.  I believe false is the default.

For **System.Windows.Controls GroupBox**:

Make sure that the [GroupBox.IsTabStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.istabstop.aspx) property is set.  This also defaults to false.

<strike>**Update:** It appears that all of your controls are being added to `groupBox3`.  You should make sure that each of them is being added only to its containing groupbox.  For example, `checkBox1`, `checkBox2`, and `checkBox3` should all be added to `flag`, which itself should be added to `groupBox1`.  `groupBox3` should only contain Back, Next, Finish, and Cancel.</strike>

Comment: There is no TabStop property for GroupBox.

Comment: Check the link.  It specifically goes to the MSDN articale for GroupBox.TabStop Property.  In addition, I tested creating a new GroupBox and verified that a) the property exists and b) it defaults to false.

Comment: Okay. Maybe checkbox is only for mouse rather than keystroke?

Comment: I updated my answer to include properties for both `System.Windows.Controls.GroupBox` and `System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox`.  My original answer was based off of the assumption that you were using the Forms GroupBox, which might explain why I found there to be a TabStop property and you didn't.

Comment: Your checkboxes should have `TabStop` (or `IsTabStop`) defaulted to true. I still think the issue is in your `flag` GroupBox not having its `TabStop` property appropriately set.

Comment: I added it when I drag it from the toolbox. And it can be found in designer code as well.

Comment: I just saw that you updated your code example so that the checkboxes are in the correct groupbox.  Were they originally in groupbox3?  If so, correcting the code so that they are now in groupbox2 might fix things.

Comment: Don't worry about groupbox name. Because there is a groupbox3 in the image. I changed it to avoid confusion. groupbox2 is for "flag".

Answer (score 2):

I found that the only way to get the tab order in WinForms group boxes is by changing the order in which the controls are added to the group boxes in the generated InitializeControl method.

If you have multiple group boxes you will have to check the order in which the group boxes are added to their container and possibly change it.

I really dislike editing generated code but as far as I can see it is the only way to fix this.

Setting the TabStop property of the group box did not help at all.