# How do I control the focus order for TextBoxes inside a panel?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I have a Form with many TextBoxes. I need some TextBoxes inside one group, and other text boxes inside another group. By group, I just need a way to make these TextBoxes appear to belong with each other.

I made two Panels and added the TextBoxes to them. Then, I placed a border around these Panels.

However, my problem is that when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the focus doesn't go to the next TextBox, but rather it goes **in a random** order to another TextBox. Sometimes the next TextBox is inside the first Panel, other times it is in the second Panel. How can I control the focus order?

This is an image to illustrate my point:

[image: an image to illustrate my point]

Comment: As others have stated, use the `TabIndex` property but do not assign the value in code. Use the designer. In Visual Studio go to the menu item labeled "View" and them from the context menu, choose "Tab Order".

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54157944/8928707) might help as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As others have said, use the `TabIndex` property to indicate the tabbing order, and the `TabStop` property to determine whether or not the control can be tabbed to at all.

However, there is a much simpler way to do this from the designer. When looking at your form in the designer, make sure your form is selected (and not a control on the form) (you can do this by clicking once in the whitespace around the form), and then choose ***View -> Tab Order***.

With the tab order designer active, you will see the `TabIndex`es of every control. Click them in the order you would like to be able to tab through them. The `TabIndex` tooltips will change from blue to white as you assign them. When you are done, choose ***View -> Tab Order*** again to return to the normal designer state.

Another thing to mention would be to suggest using `UserControl`s whenever possible. If you reuse parts of your UI with good design of `UserControl`s, you can avoid having a form with dozens and dozens of tab stops to assign, since each `UserControl` will have its own internal tabbing order that will automatically apply when placed on a Form, and you will only have to set the `TabIndex` of the `UserControl` itself.

Comment: This `Tab Order` feature made my life much easier. 1000 Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Tab order should be set like this. Both top container panel should have TabIndex 0 and 1 respectively and its child control should have TabIndex prefix by their parent control Tab Index. ie. if the Panel1 has TabIndex 0 then its child controls should have TabIndex 0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3...

**NOTE:** make sure that if the Tab Stop property of any control is set to false then cursor will not move into that control. In that case TabIndex will not work.

[image]

Comment: +1 for the efforts, I wish I could accept more than one answer, many thanks

Comment: @AgnieszkaPolec its ok, i thought u didn't get the idea from Sahuagin's solution. So, I have posted my answer with the screenshot to get understand logic easily :)

Comment: Sorry I didn't comment on the answers because I fall asleep

Answer (score 1):

When you select a textbox on your designer, you should see a property for the textbox called the [TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex(v=vs.110).aspx).  When tabbing through controls, focus goes to the component with the next highest TabIndex.

You'll want to set the TabIndex for each of the boxes so that tabbing rotates through the boxes in the order that you expect.

Comment: +1 for your efforts, I wish I could accept more than one answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the [`TabIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the `TextBox` Controls.

From MSDN : [`Control.TabIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets the tab order of the control within its container.
>
> For a control to be included in the tab order, its TabStop property
>   must be set to true.

Try This: (Example)

```
txtTextBox1.TabIndex = 1;
txtTextBox2.TabIndex = 2;
txtTextBox3.TabIndex = 3;
```

in the above example Tab Focus order is as below:

```
txtTextBox1
txtTextBox2
txtTextBox3
```

**Note:** You need to make sure that `TabStop` property of the textbox controls are set to True  otherwise tab ordering does not work,but by default when you are designing controls using `Visual Studio IDE`(using drag and drop functionality) `TabStop` property is set to `True`.

From MSDN : [Control.TabStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the user can give the focus to this control using the TAB key.

Try This: Setting `TabStop` property

```
txtTextBox1.TabIndex = 1;
txtTextBox1.TabStop = True;

txtTextBox2.TabIndex = 2;
txtTextBox2.TabStop = True;

txtTextBox3.TabIndex = 3;
txtTextBox3.TabStop = True;
```

Comment: +1 for the efforts, but there is another answer better for me, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN - Control.TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex(v=vs.110).aspx):

> A tab index can consist of any valid integer greater than or equal to
>   zero, lower numbers being earlier in the tab order. If more than one
>   control on the same parent control has the same tab index, the z-order
>   of the controls determines the order to cycle through the controls.
>
> For a control to be included in the tab order, its TabStop property
>   must be set to true.

Accordingly,

```
textbox1.TabIndex = 1; // and do the same for each one in the desired order
textbox1.TabStop = true;
```

Comment: +1 for the efforts, but there is another answer was better for me. many thanks